# GraphQL error: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have this mutation:

```
export const SET_CART_MUTATION = gql`mutation setCartMutation($vendorSlug: String!, $sessionId: String, $productId:[Int!], $prices:[PriceInput]) {
  setCart(vendorSlug: $vendorSlug, sessionId: $sessionId, productId:$productId, prices:$prices) {
    cart {
      ${CART_FIELDS}
    }
    allTicketsAdded
  }
}`
```

I want to create an array of productId but when I mutate: I get :

```
Mutation error: Error: GraphQL error: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

My setCart class is :

```
class SetCart(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        vendor_slug = graphene.String()
        session_id = graphene.String()
        product_id = graphene.List(graphene.Int)
        prices = graphene.List(PriceInput)
```

Thanks for help, and ask questions.

Comment: What query parameters did you pass to the mutation? I mean, the values of all mutation arguments.

Comment: I solved, the problem was in the mutation function, not in the arguments

Comment: Glad you solved it, would be great if you shared the solution so others can see what went wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,

If you have the same error and you're sure that's the mutation arguments are the same type as declared: the problem come from your mutation function :

```
def mutate(self, info, vendor_slug, session_id, products, prices, participants):
        # ? List of products given
        products = Product.objects.get(id=product)
        cart = Order.objects.get_cart(
            vendor_slug, info.context.user, session_id)
```

The error come from `Product.objects.get(id=product)`
because product is an array
Correction:

```
products = [Product.objects.get(id=product) for product in products]
```